# Traversing through Bash Curl search results

Tags: bash, curl, traversal

I'm trying to traverse through the results of my curl statement and then delete each URL that is returned.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i Current_Date
declare -i Three_Months_Ago

Current_Date=($(date +%s%N)/1000000)
Three_Months_Ago=(${Current_Date}-7889238000)

curl -Username:Password "URL/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Three_Months_Ago}&today&repos=generic-sgca"
```

Which returns the following:

```
{
  "results" : [ {
    "uri" : "URL/api/storage/generic-sgca/Lastest_Deploy.tar",
    "created" : "2017-09-14T11:59:14.483-06:00"
  }]
```

There are more than 50 lines like this. Now I want to be able to run another "-X DELETE" curl command that will delete each URL that is returned. Such as:

```
URL=curl -Username:Password "URL/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Three_Months_Ago}&today&repos=generic-sgca"

curl -Username:Password -X DELETE ${URL}
```

Or something like that. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i Current_Date
declare -i Three_Months_Ago

Current_Date=($(date +%s%N)/1000000)
Three_Months_Ago=(${Current_Date}-7889238000)

while read -r uri; do
curl -Username:Password  -X DELETE "$uri" 
done < <(
    curl -Username:Password "URL/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Three_Months_Ago}&today&repos=generic-sgca" | # get the list of uris
    grep -o "uri"    | # filter out everything else
    tr -d ','        | # remove commas
    awk '{print $3}'   # print just the uri
    )
```

I get this in return:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3225    0  3225    0     0   3225      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15140
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

Comment: See what your URIs look like by changing to `echo curl  -Username:Password  -X DELETE "$uri"` Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

A common Bash idiom for doing something with a variable number of input lines is the following:

```
while read -r line; do
   something_interesting "$line"

done < <(command)
```

There isn't quite enough information to write the whole script for you here, but something along the lines of this should work and give you a place to start.

```
while read -r uri; do
  curl_request_to_delete_resource "$uri"

done < <(
    curl $parameters | # get the list of uris
    grep -o "uri"    | # filter out everything else
    tr -d ','        | # remove commas
    awk '{print $3}'   # print just the uri
    )
```

Comment: Check OP for edits, can't figure out how to post code here. I've tried this and I can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you get if you replace the inner curl call with `echo`? That should help debug what's going wrong.